# Reorder array of objects based on array of strings?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, data-structures, ecmascript-6

I have the following data structures:

```
const fieldOrder = [
  'title',
  'first_name',
  'last_name',
  'address_1',
  'address_2',
  'city',
  'state',
  'zipcode',
  'country',
]

const fields = [
  {
    name: 'first_name',
    value: 'John'
  },
  {
    name: 'title',
    value: 'Mr'
  }
  ...etc
]
```

And I'd like to reorder the `fields` array of objects based on the position of the `name` key in the `fieldOrder` array. How is this possible? Perhaps with the `Array.sort` method somehow?

And, generally speaking, is this the best way to represent order?

Answer (score 2):

You could create object from the field order array and then use `sort` method to sort based on the values from that object that will be index of current element in the order array.

```js
const fieldOrder = [
  'title',
  'first_name',
  'last_name',
  'address_1',
  'address_2',
  'city',
  'state',
  'zipcode',
  'country',
].reduce((r, e, i) => {
  r[e] = i;
  return r
}, {})

const fields = [{
    name: 'first_name',
    value: 'John'
  },
  {
    name: 'title',
    value: 'Mr'
  }
].sort((a, b) => fieldOrder[a.name] - fieldOrder[b.name])

console.log(fields)
```

Answer (score 1):

Look for the index of the `name` in `fieldOrder` and use `.sort` to achieve that :

```js
const fieldOrder = [
  "title",
  "first_name",
  "last_name",
  "address_1",
  "address_2",
  "city",
  "state",
  "zipcode",
  "country"
];

const fields = [
  {
    name: "first_name",
    value: "John"
  },
  {
    name: "title",
    value: "Mr"
  }
];

const result = fields.sort((a,b) => {
  const aNdx = fieldOrder.findIndex(e => e === a.name);
  const bNdx = fieldOrder.findIndex(e => e === b.name);

  return aNdx - bNdx;
})

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort it based on the index in the array;

```js
const fieldOrder = [
    'title',
    'first_name',
    'last_name',
    'address_1',
    'address_2',
    'city',
    'state',
    'zipcode',
    'country',
  ]
  
  const fields = [
    {
        name: 'first_name',
        value: 'John'
    },
    {
        name: 'title',
        value: 'Mr'
    },
    {
        name: 'city',
        value: 'JNB'
    },
    {
        name: 'country',
        value: 'RSA'
    }
]

fields.sort( (a, b) => fieldOrder.indexOf(a.name) - fieldOrder.indexOf(b.name));

console.log(fields)
```